# How can be used a list comprehension at left side of an assignment operator?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

My code part is:

```
v=[7,0,2,5,1]               # list with any numbers
x={2,0,4}                   # set of indexes (where element of x < len(v) has been provided)
for i in x:                 # this for loop is working
    v[i]-=10
print(v)                    # good result
[-3, 0, -8, 5, -9]
```

My question is how can I replace the for cycle above with list comprehension or other more compact expression?
Note: the print only shows the new values of v
but the task would be modifying only some element of original v list.

Comment: FYI, the `enumerate` is superfluous…

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't quite answer the question but unless you're trying for some code golfing contest I hope you just go with the below. It is simple and clear - just because the code will fit in one line doesn't make it better.

```
for i in x: 
    v[i] -= 10
```

Comment: The reason for my question is only curiosity with the usage of list comprehension. Beside I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
v = [i-10 if idx in x else i for idx,i in enumerate(v)])
print(v)
```

Output:

```
[-3, 0, -8, 5, -9]
```

Comment: Note that this is more expensive since it iterates through the longer `v` instead of `x`, and does repeated membership testing in `x`; but that's the price you pay for a list comprehension here…

Comment: This isn't changing the values within v, not sure if that is what OP wanted though

Comment: @Agustin instead of using `print` if you assign back to v, it does what OP wants

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar My print only shows the new values of v but the task would be modifying only some element of original v list. So the question is if there is  something like this: v[expr]=10  where 
the expr has more values as like a list, tuple. So can be there a list comprehension at the left side of an assigment?

Answer (score 1):

May be there is not too much reason to do a list comprehension on the left side of assignment op.,
moreover of modify assignment op. but nevertheless I wanted to construct this.
So the question was how could I modify some element by an index set 
in a longer list with list comprehension (without any copy of list or usage of explicit cycle statement) . 
I could achieve this solution only with "self writing" code by using `exec()` function.

First of all I show a simple assignment *with same value*:

```
# Let the index set and the "long" list be:
>>> x={0, 2, 4}
>>> v=[0]*10
>>> str(tuple("v["+str(i)+"]" for i in x))+"="+str(len(x)*(1,))
"('v[0]', 'v[2]', 'v[4]')=(1, 1, 1)"
# So I needed to change ("'" to "") at the left side before I could execute it.
>>> str(tuple("v["+str(i)+"]" for i in x)).replace("'","")+"="+str(len(x)*(1,))
'(v[0], v[2], v[4])=(1, 1, 1)'

# Put it into `exec()` function.
>>> exec(str(tuple("v["+str(i)+"]" for i in x)).replace("'","")+"="+str(len(x)*(1,)))
>>> v
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now I show how I can decrease the list element by 1 according x set (as it was my question):

```
>>> s1=str(tuple("v["+str(i)+"]-=1" for i in x))
>>> s1
"('v[0]-=1', 'v[2]-=1', 'v[4]-=1')"
# Now I used the REG module for more efficient character replacement.
>>> import re as r
>>> r.sub(r"\(|\)|'","",s1).replace(",",";")
v[0]-=1; v[2]-=1; v[4]-=1'

# Now put them together:
>>> exec(r.sub(r"\(|\)|'","",str(tuple("v["+str(i)+"]-=1" for i in  x))).replace(",",";"))
>>> v
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   # if v was 10*[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension:

```
print([v - 10 if i in x else v for i,v in enumerate(v)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below is what you need

```
[v[i]-10 if i in x else v[i] for i in range(len(v))]
[-3, 0, -8, 5, -9]
```